# NSKeyedArchiver changing from objectForKey to intForKey

Tags: ios, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I have an app which stores data using `NSKeyedArchiver` and everything was working fine.

In the first version of the app a value X was stored as a string, but now I changed it to be stored and saved as an int. The problem is if someone updates from the old version to the newest the app crashes because `intForKey:` gets called on a key containing a String.

Is there some way during decoding to check if what is being decoded is an `int` or an object?

Comment: Are you actually calling `intForKey:` or `decodeIntegerForKey:` method? Can you post a code snippet showing how you're doing this?

Comment: Sorry, I meant     
int x = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"value"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSKeyedArchiver` doesn't actually encode primitive values. Instead, it wraps them in an `NSNumber`.

Perhaps, have you tried using `decodeObjectForKey:` instead of `decodeIntegerForKey:`?

In example,

```
id xObject = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"xObjectKey"];
self.x = [xObject integerValue];

// I believe this should work because xObject will either by an NSNumber or NSString
// Both of which respond to the selector integerValue
```